# Dynamically loading jar file into Java program

Tags: java, swing, deployment, jar, installation

I'm working on Desktop applications. I'm using JFC/Swing to build the application.

Now I want to build application that can be upgradable by changing some jar files, instead of installing entire application again.

I'm stuck with some basic steps. I want to add `JMenu` from various jar files, so I dynamically added those jar files. Now my issue is that, I want to perform some functions like adding `JInternalFrame` to the main class, which loads entire jar files. I am not able to achieve it.

Please help me with this issue, and suggest any idea to make it possible.

Comment: With dynamically added you mean without restarting your application? Or you can accept to reload your app? (because without reloading the solution is more complex)

Answer (score 2):

> Now i want to build application that can be upgradable by changing some jar files, instead of installing entire application again.

[Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)..

> Java Web Start (JWS) is the Oracle Corporation technology used to launch rich client (**Swing**, AWT, SWT) desktop applications directly from a network or internet link. It offers 'one click' installation for platforms that support Java.
>
> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, **automatic update** (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily using URLClassLoader, you can see s simple example here:
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3574